# Prometheus/grafana : extract hostname from "node_uname_info" metric and create CPU, Memory usage grafana panels

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have populated prometheus.yml -> scrape_configs -> static_configs -> targets section using multiple IP addresses. There is no DNS functionality on prometheus server nor populating hostnames (instead of IPs) is possible.

1. I want to create memory, cpu usage specific grafana panel using regexp based on nodename/hostname value. It should also have hostname in `legands`.
2. Since `hostname` info is not available in default node_exporter metrics, I am exploring possibility of leveraging `node_uname_info` metric which has hostname information.
3. I tried using `relabel_configs` and `metric_relabel_configs` but it is not serving the purpose.

Can someone please help to understand possible solution ? Thanks in advance.

**Possible metric to use:**

```
node_uname_info{domainname="(none)",machine="x86_64",nodename="xy1dcxyz111",release="3.10.0-1160.81.1.el7.x86_64",sysname="Linux",version="#1 SMP Thu Nov 24 12:21:22 UTC 2022"} 1
```

Comment: You might have more luck asking on the relevant Grafana community forum if you have not already even if it's more a Prometheus question: https://community.grafana.com

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

```
(avg by(instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="user"}[1m])) * 100) * on(instance) group_left(hostname) role{role="Apache"}
```

Hi, I stumbled upon a old writeup by Brian Brazil himself (link shared below) which helped me figure out solution. In addition, I have populated custom metric "role" which I leveraged for subsequent filtering.

https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus/

Answer (score 0):

If you know hostnames of the targets ahead of time, you might specify them as static labels next to your targets:

```yml
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["192.168.0.2:9100"]
        labels:
          instance_host: xy1dcxyz111
      - targets: ["192.168.0.3:9100", "192.168.0.3:8080"]
        labels:
          instance_host: webserver
```

This will associate provided label with every metric of corresponding target.

It might be beneficial if you want to see/work with hostnames for multiple metrics.

Comment: Since my inventory is already 1000+ nodes & growing - such mapping (possibly via manual methods) is not feasible. Hence skipped this option

Comment: @VijayGharge, yeah this solution is not great for growing targets, but still might be useful for somebody in similar situation. Regarding initial large number of target: run some simple script to generate that list in any language is rather trivial.